# How can I do a Solr search where each keyword is weighted individually?

Tags: solr

I see how you can use query functions to apply different weights to different fields being searched, but is there a way in Solr to weight the individual keywords being searched individually, so that the score can incorporate the weighting and rank my results based on that?

Imagine a search for:

```
lebron james basketball heat
```

Where `lebron` and `james` are weighted at 1.0, `basketball` is weighted at 0.9, and `heat` is weighted at 0.5.

If there isn't a way built-in to standard Solr, can you point me in the right direction for writing a plugin where I could build this functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a boost for each part of your query like this:

```
q=(lebron james)^100 (basketball)^90 (heat)^50
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the same technique used to boost fields could also boost individual terms, but now that I see the syntax it is very intuitive.